# Write SQL query without UNION or any JOIN (FULL/LEFT/RIGHT)

Tags: sql, postgresql

As weekly exercise for my database subject, i have 3 tables. Class, department and staff, where i need to list the name of the class corresponding to the staff and department name. Department name is the department where the stuff lives. The problem is that there is some staff that doesn´t live in any department so their column value is null for that.

The main structure of the tables:

- Staff(staffid (primary key), name, deptid, age)
- Class(classid (Primary key), name, meetsat, room, staffid)
- Department(deptid (primary key), name)

```
 +------------------------+
 | class || staff|| dep   |
 +------------------------+
 |  A    || 1    ||  L    |
 |  B    || 2    ||  G    |
 |  C    || 3    ||       |
 |  D    || 4    ||  L    |
 +------------------------+
```

This is what i am trying to accomplish. The staff where department_name is null has to stay empty.

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name AS "class_name" , st.name AS "staff_name", d.name AS "department_name" 
 FROM class c, staff st, department d
 WHERE c.staffid = st.staffid AND st.deptid = d.deptid
 UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT class.name AS "class_name", staff.name AS "staff_name" , NULL AS "department_name" FROM staff staff, class class, department d WHERE staff.deptid IS NULL AND staff.staffid = class.staffid;
```

This query works perfectly fine. But only by using the UNION keyword. How can i get the same result with just using correlated subqueries? (No JOIN keyword may be used)

I tried to do it with a query like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name AS "class_name" , st.name AS "staff_name", d.name AS "department_name" 
 FROM class c, staff st, department d
 WHERE (c.staffid = st.staffid AND st.deptid = d.deptid AND d.deptid IS NOT NULL) OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT DISTINCT NULL AS "department_name" FROM staff staff, class class, department d WHERE staff.deptid IS NOT NULL AND staff.staffid = class.staffid);
```

But this queries do not show me any departments where the value is null, only departments which contain a name.

How can i formulate this with just using subqueries without the JOIN/UNION keywords?

EDIT: Guys i get that there might be better ways to solve this. As i said in the beginning it is an university exercise and our professor wants us to solve this. We are going to learn about JOINs soon enough.

Comment: Is there a reason that you have the `DISTINCT` keyword in all of your queries?

Comment: That is just the left-over from all the trying i did..

Comment: Why are you limiting the query to not use the `JOIN` keyword?  Your query uses `JOIN` implicitly due to the commas in the `FROM` clause, which is a practice that has been deprecated with the ANSI-92 standard (as in 1992... more than **25 years ago**) and should *not* be used today.  Some DBMS’s don’t even fully support it anymore...  If your professor is requiring this, challenge them or leave the class.  There is absolutely no excuse for teaching this ancient syntax to anyone.

Comment: I would use a `join` and tell whoever is grading me that I used the best tool for the job

Comment: As i said this is an exercise guys.. My professor wants us to use it with subqueries, ask him why he wants that :D It is not like we won´t learn JOINs in the course (actually it´s the next topic) , he wants us to learn the concepts i think. He is actually a really good prof, for that matter^^

Comment: Please tell your professor that it's stupid to teach such an outdated join syntax. A join is a join regardless whether you use the ancient implicit joins in the where clause or the modern explicit `JOIN` keyword.  If he doesn't believe you, refer him to these comments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use subquery behind `SELECT`

```
SELECT c.name AS "class_name" , 
       st.name AS "staff_name", 
       (SELECT d.name FROM department d WHERE st.deptid = d.deptid) AS "department_name" 
FROM class c, staff st
WHERE c.staffid = st.staffid
```

The subquery behind select has to always return just one value (since staff belongs to one department). If the staff does not belong to any then it returns `NULL` and the staff is not eliminated in the result (when compared to inner join).

It is possible to solve it even without old join syntax, however, it is really obscure solution :)

```
SELECT c.name AS "class_name" , 
       (SELECT st.name FROM staff st WHERE c.staffid = st.staffid) AS "staff_name", 
       (SELECT
          (SELECT d.name FROM department d WHERE st.deptid = d.deptid)
        FROM staff st WHERE c.staffid = st.staffid
       ) AS "department_name" 
FROM class c
```

Comment: This does not answer the question without using a join. Using old syntax doesn't make it correct. :)

Comment: I meant the keywords JOIN and any combination, not a join itself sir.

Comment: @NumanTakács what would be the point of preventing you from using the word JOIN but use a comma-JOIN instead...?

Answer (score 0):

Learn to use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Then, you would probably recognize right away that you need a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.name AS class_name, st.name AS staff_name" d.name AS department_name 
FROM class c LEFT JOIN
     staff st
     ON c.staffid = st.staffid LEFT JOIN
     department d
     ON st.deptid = d.deptid;
```

I doubt the `SELECT DISTINCT` is needed either.  But I left it in because you would know the data better than I do.